# My smoke renders as squares/cubes

Tags: rendering, animation, smoke-simulation

I'm making an animation scene where black fog swallows a grassy field, but I have a problem with the smoke simulation. In the view port it looks fine, but when I render the smoke it is boxed and squared, and looks like cubes (I have baked the simulation).

I have tried different things, from people with similar problem, but nothing works..

Any idea why, or advice?

Thanks :)

**example:**

[image: Smoke with cubes]

**Smoke domain set up:**

[image]

**Smoke compositing:**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried increasin the resolution?

Comment: Yes, if you mean resolution in the render tap

Comment: No, I meant the smoke domain resolution, your divisions is currently set to 64.  Think of the domain as the smoke simulation volume.  When baked, the domain is chopped up into cubes, the more cubes you have, the finer the resolution of the smoke.  Here you have a very low number of cubes, so you see blocks. The more cubes you have the longer it takes to bake.

Comment: It worked!
Thanks alot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Increasing resolution divisions in domain and, in smoke high resolution fixed the problem.

Thanks to Merlin.

Comment: But also maybe [edit] to add the details from Merlin's comment, to make your answer more complete.